# OBIEE 12c: Clickable pie charts

Tags: obiee

As a first time OBIEE user, I've built an analysis containing a pie chart and added it to a dashboard. I want to be able to click on a slice of the pie chart and it should open a new page or analysis. I tried using Action Links but that seems to be working only for the column heading of a table but not for table contents or in my case the pie charts. Is this a possibility in OBIEE 12c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Action links will work on the value too. Check out the documentation and the embedded video: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/biee/BIEUG/GUID-63576665-7BFE-4D1E-ABB9-51B8AAFBB940.htm#GUID-63576665-7BFE-4D1E-ABB9-51B8AAFBB940

Comment: Thanks Chris. That was very helpful. I've got one more question. Can you help me with that please?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50697291/obiee-12c-overlapping-labels-in-pie-chart