# OBIEE 12c : Overlapping labels in pie chart

Tags: obiee

I've created 2 pie charts in an analysis and one of them seems to have its labels overlapping while the other has callouts and prevents any overlaps. I have created them in the exact same way and they both have the same properties.

Another strange thing is, this doesn't occur all the time. sometimes when I open an analysis/dashboard, both the pie charts look fine and when I refresh the page or come back to it later, then one of the chart has overlapping labels. Can anyone help me fix this.

[image]

Comment: Does the page refresh change the actual data thatbis being rendered? Like applying prompts?

Comment: No it doesn't. In fact, no prompts applied at the moment. Just 2 pie charts next to each other.

Comment: Are you using a supported browser? Cleared browser cache already?

Comment: Tried using both IE and Chrome. Same issue. Just cleared the cache and checked, still no luck.

Comment: Check out MOS Doc ID Doc ID 2260470.1 - you'll have to live with it at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Check out MOS Doc ID Doc ID 2260470.1 - you'll have to live with it at the moment